# Custom domain and Azure Kubernetes with ingress controller AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've followed this doc from microsoft [Deploy an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress) and have successfully deployed a managed Kubernetes cluster (AKS) with nginx ingress controller.  it works with https as expected.

However, the domain that responds of the format **subdomain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com**.  However I would like to use my own custom domain **www.somedomain.com**.  I then add a CNAME entry to my custom domain, pointing to the public ip address configured by the kubernetes cluster.

However, when I do this, I get a response on the browser of

**default backend - 404**

It looks like I need to change the public ip address in Azure (or somewhere) so that it understands that it will be used by a custom domain as well as by an azure subdomain.

I've had a look at the command:

az network

command.  However, it's not very clear is this is the right command to use or not.  Does anyone know how I can make the changes required so that my custom FQDN can be routed properly to my kubernetes cluster?

thanks

Comment: You can try to point your custom FQDN to Azure FQDN of Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'default backend 404' indicates that it is hitting the ingress controller. If it were being rejected or not reaching I'd expect a generic 404 without the 'default backend' bit. This response means it is hitting the ingress contoller but the inress controller doesn't know where to send it on to. This is because there's no ingress route/resource matching the host of that request. The steps to create that route/resource are specific to the domain so the ingress rules only match for the azure domain and not the custom one. I think you'll need to go back and repeat the ingress resource and certificate steps for your custom domain as those steps are domain-specific.

Comment: Great - it works Ryan :-).  Thanks a lot. I simply added another route to my yaml file with the new domain.  I'd previously set the CNAME up so, the ingress controller immediately started routing correcly.  I've added the full yaml below in case it help anyone else.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the yaml that worked for me.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - subdomain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    - subdomain.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: subdomain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: aks-helloworld
          servicePort: 80
  - host: subdomain.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: aks-helloworld
          servicePort: 80
```

See here for worked through example: [Deploy an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress)

Comment: Hi, first thank you for posting the full yml. Did you had to create an Azure DNS resource etc? Or using external DNS and pointing your A record to the ingress controller was sufficient ?

Answer (score 4):

I've been facing the same problem the last couple of days and came across an [awesome step-by-step guide](https://github.com/fbeltrao/aks-letsencrypt) which allowed me to use custom domains and provisioning certs with Letsencrypt.

If you want to use your own custom certificates you may want to [follow this article instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its sad that microsoft is pushing Azure DNS instead of guiding how to solve the problem with an external DNS provider.